# count number of objects that's eligible for GC

Tags: java, garbage-collection, scjp

Good Evening, please look at this code samples that demonstrates the number of objects that's eligible for GC:

```
public class CardBoard {

Short story = 5;

CardBoard go(CardBoard cb) {
    cb = null;
    return cb;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    CardBoard c1 = new CardBoard();
    CardBoard c2 = new CardBoard();
    CardBoard c3 = c1.go(c2);
    c1 = null;
   // do Stuff

   }
}
```

i see that there's four objects that's eligible for GC when do Stuff is reached that's c3 and it's associated story object and c1 and it's associated story object, what do you see?

Comment: ...are we in an interview? :-)

Comment: exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109717/java-garbage-collection-and-null-reference

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is exactly **1** object eligible for GC - the one previously referenced by `c1`. `c3` points to `null` (`CardBoard.go()` always returns `null`).

Also remember that `c1` and `c2` variables are only references, not objects. Thus they don't need to be garbage collected. They live on stack, not on heap.

Finally don't be fooled by:

```
CardBoard go(CardBoard cb) {
  cb = null;
  return cb;
}
```

this only nullifies `cb` reference (parameter), not `c2` reference.

---

```
Short story = 5;
```

is a separate gotcha. If it was `short story` then it wouldn't count as a separate object. But `Short` is an object, so technically `CardBoard` points to another object eligible for GC. However! Due to primitive wrappers caching `5` is actually part of `Short` static cache and is never really eligible for GC. In other words object of type `Short` representing `5` is always referenced by `static` cache in `Short`.

Here comes the best part. If it was:

```
Short story = 5000;
```

then the answer would be... **2**. That's because `Short.valueOf((short)5000)` always returns new instance of `Short` (eligible for GC) while `Short.valueOf(5)` always returns the same one.

Wow, that was tricky!

Comment: completely forgot about that cache. hats off to you.

Comment: when you say "- the one previously referenced by c1" ,what does it mean ?

Comment: @Imposter: At first line you see: `c1 = new CardBoard()` and at the end `c1 = null`. The `new CardBoard()` is the one eligible for GC.

Comment: please tell me about the static cache, i don't understand the difference between Short story=5 and Short story=5000;

Comment: @Eslam: please open another question or better - research. This was discussed many times and is also part of OCJP exam.